# Add zeros in front of a number

Tags: text-processing, python3

I have a file that looks like this and was computed with Python:

```
1.00000100e+07  
1.00000000e+04  
1.11000111e+08  
1.11000000e+05
```

Now, I would like to obtain something like this:

```
010000010  
000010000  
111000111  
000111000
```

The idea is that I would like to add zeros to obtain a fixed format of 9 bits. The Python code that I wrote gives me the binary numbers, but for further decoding I need these binary numbers to have 9 bits. I tried to obtain them in the desired format from Python, but I was not able to do that.

I hope my explanation is clear.

Update:
Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3  

import numpy as np  
from numpy import genfromtxt  
import os  

day = os.environ.get('day')  
Array = genfromtxt("SUC_diffzeros_"+str(day)+".csv")  
final = np.zeros(len(Array))
    
def decimaltobinary(x):

    for i in range(len(x)):
        
        print(x[i])
        final[i] = "{0:09b}".format(x[i])
        print(final)
    var = np.column_stack([Array, final])
    np.savetxt("SUC_diffzeros_"+str(day)+".csv", var, fmt='%.8e')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    val = Array.astype(int)
    decimaltobinary(val)
```

Comment: Can you show your python code? I am asking because, you could convert that to float / int and to `bin(yourvalue)`

Comment: I added it in the post @ValentinBajrami

Comment: If it's about a tool based approach at reformatting numbers, the question is welcome here. If it's about a python programming question about formatting binary numbers, [so] would be more appropriate.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, but that `fmt='%.8e'` really [looks like](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) you want it to be `fmt='%09d'`

Comment: It just adds a new zero at the end of the number, not in front @roaima

Comment: Quick hack around (setting `Array = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)` at the top to generate data, and commenting the `final[i]=…` and `print(final)`). Changing the format for `savetxt` definitely seems to do what I'd expect

Comment: @JeffSchaller that question has been closed/deleted too

Comment: Odd, given the comments I saw there. Well, I'm happy to reopen this one, the.  Thanks for the heads-up, roaima!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk '{printf "%09.15g\n", $0}' < file
010000010
000010000
111000111
000111000
```

Or:

```
$ awk '{printf "%09d\n", $0}' < file
010000010
000010000
111000111
000111000
```

Which also converts to integer. You'd see the difference on numbers such as `1.1` or `111000111.9` where the former would give:

```
0000001.1
111000111.9
```

And the latter:

```
000000001
111000111
```

See also `awk '{printf "%09.0f\n", $0}'` which rounds:

```
000000001
111000112
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put sprintf "%09d", $_;' file
```

OR

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put sprintf q[%09d], $_;' file
```

Sample Input:

```
1.00000100e+07  
1.00000000e+04  
1.11000111e+08  
1.11000000e+05
```

Sample Output:

```
010000010
000010000
111000111
000111000
```

According to the docs, *"This function (`sprintf`) is mostly identical to the C library's sprintf and printf functions. The only difference between the two functions is that sprintf returns a string while the printf function writes to a filehandle. sprintf returns a Str, not a literal."*

The directive `"%09d"` or `q[%09d]` treats the input as a signed integer (in decimal), left padding with `0` zero up to `9` nine digits.

Nota bene: if necessary `sprintf` also has the `#` directive, which (among other things), *'prefix(es) non-zero binary with "0b" or "0B"'.* This `#` directive might be useful if if you change your Python output format (see the docs for details).

https://docs.raku.org/routine/sprintf
https://raku.org